# Find highest average in JavaScript 2d array of students scores

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Yesterday, I faced this interview question. Initially, it seemed pretty easy, at least logically. 
But somehow, I could not make it work in JavaScript.

**Here is a 2d array of student scores, student names might be repeated multiple times. If this is the case, sum up all the scores and divide by the number of occurrences to find the average, do the Math.floor if necessary.**

```
var arr = [
    ["Bobby","87"],
    ["Charles","100"],
    ["Eric","65"],
    ["Charles","22"],
    ["Charles","37"],
    ["Eric","49"]]
```

So, `Charles` average score would be `Math.floor((100+22+37)/3) = 53`
And, for `Eric` it would be `Math.floor((65+49)/2) = 57`.

So highest average would be `["Bobby","87"]`.

So far what I have tried fruitlessly..

```
var op_arr = [];
arr.each(function(item) {
    var sum = 0;
    var itemCount = 1;
    var checkFlag = isItemInArray(arr,item);
    if(checkFlag) {
        itemCount++;
        sum += item[1];
    }
});
function isItemInArray(array,item) {
    for(let i = 0;i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i][0] === item[0]) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this does not work.
Please help me and explain the logic.

Comment: that didn't work! surprising, because arrays don't have an `.each` method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use some code to convert the list into a hash map based on the fact that there can be multiple of the same student.

```
var arr = [
    ["Bobby","87"],
    ["Charles","100"],
    ["Eric","65"],
    ["Charles","22"],
    ["Charles","37"],
    ["Eric","49"]
];

var scores = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var student = arr[i];

    if (!scores.hasOwnProperty(student[0]))
        scores[student[0]] = []

    scores[student[0]].push(student[1])
}
```

The result should be:

```
{
    "Bobby": ["87"],
    "Charles": ["100", "22", "37"],
    "Eric": ["65", "49"]
}
```

And now you can do a second pass over the object to calculate the average

```
for (var key in scores) {
    if (!scores.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    var total = scores[key].reduce(function(next, cur) { 
        return next + parseInt(cur);
    }, 0);

    scores[key] = Math.floor(total / scores[key].length);
}

console.log(scores);
```

I'm sure you can make it a lot more elegant using ES6 features, but this should give you an idea of one solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could first get all average values of each person and then get the highest average of the temporary result.

If more than one person have the same score, all persons are included.

```js
var array = [["Bobby", "87"], ["Charles", "100"], ["Eric", "65"], ["Charles", "22"], ["Charles", "37"], ["Eric", "49"]],
    highest = array
        .reduce(function (r, a) {
            var i = r.findIndex(b => a[0] === b[0]);
            if (i !== -1) {
                r[i][1] = (r[i][1] * r[i][2] + +a[1]) / ++r[i][2];
            } else {
                r.push(a.concat(1));
            }
            return r;
        }, [])
        .reduce(function (r, a, i) {
            if (!i || r[0][1] < a[1]) {
                return [a.slice(0, 2)];
            }
            if (r[0][1] === a[1]) {
                r.push(a.slice(0, 2));
            }
            return r;
        }, []);

console.log(highest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can following this approach

- **Collate** all the scores for a name in an array of scores using `reduce`
- **Iterate** the result using `map` and **compute the average** of scores array using `reduce` again.

**Demo**

```js
var fnSumAvgArray = (arr) => arr.reduce( ( a, c ) => a + c, 0 )/arr.length;

var arr = [
    ["Bobby","87"],
    ["Charles","100"],
    ["Eric","65"],
    ["Charles","22"],
    ["Charles","37"],
    ["Eric","49"]];
var output = Object.values( arr.reduce( (a,c) => ( 
     a[c[0]] = (a[c[0]] || { name : c[0], scores : [] }), //check if accumulator already has been initialized for this name or else intialize
     a[ c[ 0 ] ].scores.push ( +c[1] ),  //push the score into the name based score array
     a ) , {}) ) //return  the accumulator
.map( s => ( 
     s.avg = fnSumAvgArray(s.scores),  s 
));
      
console.log( output );
```

Comment: Could you please explain and break down a bit arr.reduce part? I am not understanding it clearly.

Comment: @StrugglingCoder I have put the comments there.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var arr = [
    ["Bobby","87"],
    ["Charles","100"],
    ["Eric","65"],
    ["Charles","22"],
    ["Charles","37"],
    ["Eric","49"]];
    var x, students=[], counter=[], scoreSums=[], name, i=0;
    for(x in arr) {
      name = arr[x][0];
      j = students.indexOf(name);
      if(j < 0) {
        students[i] = name;
        counter[i] = 1;
        scoreSums[i] = parseInt(arr[x][1]);
        i++;
      } else {
        scoreSums[j] += parseInt(arr[x][1]); 
        counter[j]++;
      }
    }
    
    var maxMean = 0, mean;
    for(i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
      mean = scoreSums[i] / counter[i];
      if(mean > maxMean) {
        name = students[i];
        maxMean = mean;
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('maxMean').innerHTML='Highest average is '+ name+' at '+maxMean;
    console.log(name, maxMean);
```

```html
<div id="maxMean"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 'round the houses' approach. It is a slightly longer way to write it out but I think it's human readable which should help with the concept.

I've commented the code below.

```js
var arr = [
  ["Bobby", "87"],
  ["Charles", "100"],
  ["Eric", "65"],
  ["Charles", "22"],
  ["Charles", "37"],
  ["Eric", "49"]
];

let objects = [];
let names = [];

for (let item of arr) {
  // Get unique names
  if (names.indexOf(item[0]) <= 0) {
    names.push(item[0]);
  }
  // Create object rather than array
  let score = {
    name: item[0],
    score: parseInt(item[1])
  }
  objects.push(score);
}
// Work out average based on name
function countScore(name) {
  let count = 0;
  let total = 0;
  for (let object of objects) {
    if (object.name === name) {
      count += 1;
      total += object.score
    }
  }
  let avgScore = total / count;
  console.log(name + ': ' + avgScore)
}
// Run function for each unique name
for (let name of names) {
  countScore(name);
}
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
let findMaxAvg = (arr) => {
let studmap = new Map();
    arr.forEach((item,ind) => {
        let [name,score] = [item[0],item[1]];
        !studmap.has(name) ? studmap.set(name,[score,1]) : studmap.set(name, 
            [studmap.get(name)[0]+score,studmap.get(name)[1]+1])
    });
    return Math.max(...[...studmap.values()].map(sdata => 
  Math.round(sdata[0]/sdata[1])));

}

var arr = [
["Bobby","87"],
["Charles","100"],
["Eric","200"],
["Charles","22"],
["Charles","37"],
["Eric","49"]];
console.log(findMaxAvg(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways you can solve this as per the solutions provided above. I've also encountered this question before and I used

> [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

to collect all students and their scores and return array with [name, average].

```
const scores = [['brian', 80], ['brian', 90], ['brian', 65], ['robhy', 85], ['robhy', 75], ['ryan', 75], ['murphy', 85]];

const calculateHigestAvg = (scores)=>{

    let studentObj = new Map();
    let score = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        if (studentObj.has(scores[i][0])) {
            const studentScoreArr = studentObj.get(scores[i][0])
            studentScoreArr.push(scores[i][1]);
            studentObj.set(scores[i][0], studentScoreArr);
        } else {
            studentObj.set(scores[i][0], [scores[i][1]]);
        }
    }
    return Array.from(studentObj.entries())
        .map((item, index)=>{
            return [item[0], Math.floor(item[1].reduce((a, b) => a + b) / item[1].length)]
    }
    , 0)        
}

calculateHigestAvg(scores);

// results
[["brian", 78],["robhy", 80],["ryan", 75],["murphy", 85]]
```